# How to use tags in included/imported tasks?

Tags: ansible

There is an example playbook with the main task:

```yaml
---
- name: Include tasks
  include_tasks: include_task.yml
  # args:
  #   apply:
  #     tags: task
  tags: task

- name: Import tasks
  import_tasks: import_task.yml
  tags: task

- name: Main task
  debug:
    msg: The main task
  tags: main
```

**include_task.yml**:

```yaml
---
- name: Subtask3
  debug:
    msg: Subtask3 include
  tags: task1

- name: Subtask4
  debug:
    msg: Subtask4 include
  tags: task2
```

**import_task.yml**:

```yaml
---
- name: Subtask1
  debug:
    msg: Subtask1 import
  tags: task1

- name: Subtask2
  debug:
    msg: Subtask2 import
  tags: task2
```

A few of examples expected usages:

```sh
❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "include": "include_task.yml",
    "include_args": {}
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask3 include"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask4 include"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask1 import"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask2 import"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "The main task"
}

❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t main
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "The main task"
}
```

And a few examples of wrong usages:

```sh
❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "include": "include_task.yml",
    "include_args": {}
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask1 import"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask2 import"
}

❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task,task1
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "include": "include_task.yml",
    "include_args": {}
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask3 include"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask1 import"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask2 import"

❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task,task2
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "include": "include_task.yml",
    "include_args": {}
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask4 include"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask1 import"
}
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask2 import"
```

If I uncomment the fragment with:

```yaml
args:
    apply:
      tags: task
```

it returns "valid" output only for: `❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task`

I would like to achieve: when I use **task** tag, both tasks from include_task.yml or/and import_task.yml are executed.
When I use **task,task1** tags only the first subtask will be executed. And the similar situation for **task,task2** tags.

Generally I use tags only in main.yml file. But sometimes I need a larger granulation, so I want to use additional tags in included/imported tasks.
Is this possible?

I'm not sure if this is the correct, proper use of nested tags for import_tasks:

```sh
❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task2
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask2 import"
}

❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task1
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": "Subtask1 import"
}
```

It seems to me that for a larger playbook, it would be better to use: `ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task,task1` instead of `ansible-playbook playbooks/playground.yml -t task1`. Because tag task1 can be used in several places.

Answer (score 5):

The results are by design. Quoting from [Tag inheritance for includes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tag-inheritance-for-includes-blocks-and-the-apply-keyword):

> If you add tags to an include, they apply only to the include itself, not to any tasks in the included file

This explains the 'wrong usages'

- `-t task` The file is included, but *Subtask3* and *Subtask4* tagged *task1* and *task2* respectively do not execute. Imported *Subtask1* and *Subtask2* execute because they inherit the tag *task* from the import.
- `-t task,task1` *Subtask3* executes because *task1* applies. *Subtask1* and *Subtask2* execute because *task* applies
- `-t task,task2` The same as above but *Subtask4* executes instead of *Subtask3*

The fragment below applies the tag *task* to the included tasks. This explains the 'valid' results.

```yaml
args:
    apply:
      tags: task
```

The tasks below solve the problems. The file *include_task.yml* will be always included and the tag *task* will be applied to included tasks

```yaml
    - include_tasks: include_task.yml
      args:
        apply:
          tags: task
      tags: always
    - import_tasks: import_task.yml
      tags: task
```

See abridged results below

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml | grep msg:
  msg: Subtask3 include
  msg: Subtask4 include
  msg: Subtask1 import
  msg: Subtask2 import
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t task | grep msg:
  msg: Subtask3 include
  msg: Subtask4 include
  msg: Subtask1 import
  msg: Subtask2 import
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t task1 | grep msg:
  msg: Subtask3 include
  msg: Subtask1 import
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -t task2 | grep msg:
  msg: Subtask4 include
  msg: Subtask2 import
```

You can't expect *`-t task,task1`* or *`-t task,task2`* to be more restrictive compared to *`-t task`*.